# Difference between Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

Tags: android, path, environment

What's the difference between

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

and

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

or

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getCanonicalPath()
```

or

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

I know what getAbsolutePath(), getCanonicalPath() and getPath() are.

I see in some examples Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is used like this:

```
getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/somefolder/anotherfolder/"
```

What confuses me is what getExternalStorageDirectory() itself as default refers to and why in some cases people use extra methods and when it is alright to use simply getExternalStorageDirectory() without anything extra to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know what getAbsolutePath(), getCanonicalPath() and getPath() are.

Then you already know the answer to your original question ("What's the difference between..."), since the only thing that are different are those calls.

> what getExternalStorageDirectory() itself as default refers to

It refers to the root of external storage. When the user mounts their Android device via a USB cable and gets a drive letter or volume or something, that drive points to the directory that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` points to.

Generally speaking, developers should not be using `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, but instead `getExternalFilesDir()` and kin on `Context`, or `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on `Environment`.

> why in some cases people use extra methods

Well, you have to create `File` objects pointing at some location on external storage somehow. While it is better to use the proper `File` constructor for that, some lazy programmers use string concatenation. And for that, you need a string.

> when it is alright to use simply getExternalStorageDirectory() without anything extra to it?

Never, or close to it, simply because it is not a useful value on its own. That's akin to asking when you would use `C:` in Windows programming. That's a drive letter, and rarely is a simple drive letter on its own sufficient. We need a path to a directory or file, and for that, we need to add stuff to `C:` (at minimum, a backslash).

Comment: When I mount my Android device via a USB cable two volumes come up with names "Phone" and "Card". Apps' folders are in "Phone" volume. Based on what you explained "Phone" is my root of external storage directory. Am I right? If that's true external storage directory is not physically meaning external memory card of my phone(removable one) and internal storage directory is always physically internal (non-removable one). Am I get this correctly?

Comment: @MajidPoureftekhari: "Am I right?" -- yes. What those volumes are named, and whether there is more than the external storage volume, is up to the manufacturer. "external storage directory is not physically meaning external memory card of my phone(removable one)" -- [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not generally [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on devices manufactured since 2011.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs one returns File Object, and getAbsolutePath() is File class method.